# name "suffix" is missing from import mapping list

Tags: import

name "suffix" does not appear in the field names to be mapped.  I have that data in my contacts.csv file but can't see how to map it.

Answer (score 2):

Use individual suffix/prefix option for this.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for "name suffix" and just "suffix."